# Microsoft Access: How to convert number to string using update query?

Tags: type-conversion, ms-access-2010

I have an integer field with numbers ranging from 1000 to 99999. I want to convert this number field to a 5-character text field. This means all 4 digit numbers will have 0 added in front when converted to text. Example: 1000 in integer must be converted to 01000, etc.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query change the field to:

```
NewFieldName: format([OldFieldName],'00000')
```

This will convert the number to a text value.

Comment: I tried to do this and it didn't work. Could you review the code for me?  UPDATE [MyTable] SET [MyTable].CodeText = text([MyTable].[Code],'00000');